# Using ConvertBack function on OneWay binding instead of the Convert function

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a converter that takes in a IEnumerable and returns one string with multiple lines. The convertback function does the opposite, takes in a string with multiple lines and returns a List. I'm using it in a few places and it works great.

My question is, I now have locations where I want to use the Convert and ConvertBack functions in reverse (e.g. on a OneWay binding, it uses the ConvertBack function) Is this possible in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating such a converter is possible, for example:

```
class ListStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public bool IsListToString { get; set; }

    public ListStringConverter()
    {
        IsListToString = true;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return IsListToString ? FromListToString(value) : FromStringToList(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return IsListToString ? FromStringToList(targetListItem) : FromListToString(targetListItem);
    }


    public object FromListToString(object list)
    {
       .... // Conversion Logic
    }

    public object FromStringToList(object myString)
    {
       .... // Conversion Logic
    }

}
```

In the XAML you can declare it like this

```
<ListStringConverter x:Key="StringToListConverter " IsListToString ="False" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This would work though I need a method that would not force me to go back and edit pre-existing code.

Comment: @Lukiahas The `IsListToString` property is actually set here from the XAML when the Converter is created, although you could also set it as the `ConverterParameter` when the converter gets used

Comment: As Rachel said, I don't think you'll need to edit pre-existing code (except the converter), since you have a default value for the IsListToString (in the converter's constructor) you just need to make a slight modification to your existing converter.

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea if its possible or not, but I wouldn't do such a thing even if it was possible.

Converters are used to convert a bound value from one value to another, and if you change that then you'd be changing part of the core functionality in WPF, which will make it very confusing in the future for other developers.

I would instead just make a second converter that does the reverse conversion for you.

If the conversion is very long, I sometimes will pull the duplicated code out and put it in its own method in the converter class file, and make both converters just call that method.

Comment: You're probably right. I was hoping there was a simple to do it in pure XAML. I just created a static TextToList method and a static ListToText method and just had two converters reference them. Thanks.

Comment: @Lukiahas [Blachshma's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13125040/302677) is actually a decent way of doing this too using a single Converter, although you can set the boolean value as the `ConverterParameter` instead of setting it when the converter gets created if you want instead.